# Group By Two Columns and Taking Maximum Value of Another Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is called "dataset" and has 3 columns (driverid, week, loghour)

```
driverId   week     loghour
int         int        int
```

Example Data

```
10,1,70
10,2,70
10,5,70
10,10,50
10,47,74
11,11,77
11,15,0
11,23,70
11,32,82
13,35,51
14,8,60
14,11,45
```

**Question**

Show for each driver their ID and the week in which they drove the greatest number of hours

**My solution**

```
select driverid, week, max(loghour) as maxhours from dataset group by driverid, week order by maxhours desc;
```

My solution doesn't work.

**Expected Output:**

```
10,47,74
11,32,82
13,35,51
14,8,60
```

**Note:** *For those who want to try, I am giving the table creation and insert codes to avoid time waste*.

> CREATE TABLE dataset (driverid int, week int, loghour int) ;
>
> INSERT INTO dataset (driverid, week, loghour) VALUES (10,1,70),
> (10,2,70), (10,5,70), (10,10,50), (10,47,74), (11,11,77), (11,15,0),
> (11,23,70), (11,32,82), (13,35,51), (14,8,60), (14,11,45) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two table join sql.

```
 select  dataset.* from 
(select  driverid, max(loghour) as maxhours from dataset
 group by driverid) t  
 join   dataset  on dataset.driverid = t.driverid and t.maxhours = dataset.loghour
 order by dataset.driverid
```

output is

10  47  74

11  32  82

13  35  51

14  8   60

Comment: test comment test comment

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation
for the `rank()` function:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank

Create a SELECT whose output rows mention
both `week` and rank.

Now it's easy -- pick out the rows
with rank of `1` to find the answer.

---

It is possible for two or more weeks
to be best, having identical hours.
Depending on your requirements,
outputting multiple tied week IDs
might be correct.
Or you might want to use a GROUP BY
to arbitrarily output the MIN() or MAX() week ID.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query using correlated subquery in `WHERE` clause:

```
select * 
from dataset d
where loghour=(select max(loghour) from dataset where driverid=d.driverid)
;
```